# php to load variable php file depending on the browser width

Tags: php, browser

Hi I am currently using jQuery to load a variable php layout depending on the browser width.

```
function setLocation(url) {
   if (window.location.href.indexOf(url) === -1)
      window.location = url;
}

function reloadPage(width) {
    width = parseInt(width);
    if (width < 701) {
        setLocation("yournarrowpage.php");
    } else if (width < 900) {
        setLocation("yourmediumpage.php");
    } else {
        setLocation("yourwidepage.php");
    }
}

$(function() {
   reloadPage($(this).width());
   $(window).resize(function() {
       reloadPage($(this).width());
   });
});
```

Is it possible to accomplish this with just php?

If yes, how? Please help.

**Why do I want to do this when I can simply re-arrange my layout with CSS?**

I do not want to use the CSS property `#div { display:none }` as the issue is that my layouts are loaded with very many images, javascript and also widgets.

I even tried a responsive layout but unfortunately some of the image details are hardly visible in small screens.

Using css property `display:none`, will still loads the un-displayed content wasting a lot of bandwidth. Lets say for a mobile browser to load 1.5 MB of site and then hide 1.2 MB of it???? Well that may not be a good idea.

For smaller browsers these widgets will not make any sense, hence I would want to load a lighter version of the same.

**This is what I think. Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong as I am still a novice when it comes to programming and am still in the learning stage.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine CSS media queries and javascript to prevent loading of the larger items/areas you don't want to load...

```
if ($('window').width() > 1000) {

 // load your full functions and stylesheet 

}

if ($('window').width() < 1000) {

 // load your narrow functions and stylesheet 

}
```

I've recently combined css media queries in a method similar to this, and then added animations to help make the transition less painful.. it's quite nice.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with attempting this in PHP is that you cannot tell the client width from your web server, which means you would have to dip into the [request headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html).

There is a library to help with [device detection using PHP on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/).

Finally a word or two of warning. You will need to keep this script up to date in order for it to keep working. The methods it uses to tell what the device is falls under the banner of "browser sniffing", which relies on browsers sending through certain headers, which are subject to change in later versions / new browsers. Also, most of the time, you simply don't want to force mobile users to view a mobile version of your website, so if you do decide to implement things this way, give people an option to view the normal website on their mobiles.

Answer (score 0):

PHP just outputs text to the client.  It knows absolutely nothing about the client that the client doesn't tell it.

I say client, because there is no guarantee that the software that initiated the request to your PHP script is even a browser.

You've ruled out CSS, but honestly, if you don't want to use javascript then it's the only other option you have.  The selectors in CSS3 are really quite powerful and you can make the same page appear completely different for different browser widths.